# Why is uniquely constrained field failing on update, in Grails

Tags: hibernate, validation, grails, spring-security, grails-orm

When i have a custom identity attribute mapped in a domain class, why does hibernate check for unique constraint? When i update an object, the validation fails despite the fact that the posted field value is the same as that stored in DB! This occurs, even if I make no change to the form (ensuring dirty: false and no property binding errors).
I have a Grails domain class like below:

```
class User {
  Long profileId
  String email
  String username
  String password
  String title
  String firstname
  String lastname
  String zipCode
  Date lastLoginDate

  static constraints = {
      profileId nullable: true, blank: true
      email blank: false, unique: true, email: true
      username blank: false, unique: true
      password blank: false
      lastLoginDate nullable: true

      firstname nullable: true
      lastname nullable: true
      zipCode nullable: true
  }

  static mapping = {
    table 'USER_PROFILE'
    id name:"profileId", column: "profile_id", generator: "sequence", params: [sequence:'userprofile_sequence']
    version false
  }

}
```

Now, when i create a user with minimum attribute set, a record is created. But when i try to update the same object like:
    def user = User.findByUsername('akeel')
    user.lastLoginDate = new Date()
    user.save(flush: true)
Nothing happens, because unique validation check fails. I can bypass the validation by doing 
    user.save(validate: false, flush: true)
But, that's not an option, as i need to validate the zipCode, whenever a user adds it.

I had to set the constraint for the custom identity column, profileId, as nullable true, to resolve the 'repeated column in mapping' problem as proposed as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457727/how-to-solve-grails-error-repeated-column-in-mapping-for-entity-on-existing-pos#comment5139677_4654921).

This question is exactly like the one discussed [here](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Why-is-uniquely-constrained-field-failing-on-update-td3731538.html), but the solutions proposed didn't work for me.

I am using grails 2.1.2, let me know if anything else is required to understand the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that a custom property name for the primary key doesn't work in Grails. I've tested with Grails 2.0.4, 2.2.4 and 2.3.4 and they all fail to recognise `profileId` as the primary key. `User.get(1)` works fine, but `user.ident()` returns `null`. I would certainly raise an issue in the Grails JIRA.

The simplest solution is to remove the `profileId` property and just use the builtin `id` instead. Then just remove the `name:` value from the custom mapping. In other words, you should end up with

```
id column: "profile_id", generator: "sequence", params: [sequence:'userprofile_sequence']
```

Comment: Thanks, changed to the suggested solution, and it worked perfectly.

Comment: As a workaround, you can just set `user.properties.id=0L` (as linked in the original post) when updating the user object, and GORM will validate the object/unique properties and re-save it correctly.