# Grails unique constraint fail to update

Tags: grails, grails-orm, unique-constraint

I know that this issue related to other posts, but none of them solve my problem.

I'm using `Grails 2.5.1`, using oracle database.

I got a `domain class CardMaster`. It contains `user_id, card_no and password`.

In constrain I define `card_no` is `unique` by `user_id`.

Then I'd like to use `user_id` as a `Primary Key`, so I map `id` by:

```
id name:'user_id', generator: 'assigned'
```

However, when I find and update record by `findByUser_id`. I got a error. It says that the `card_no` must be unique and fail to save.

I read [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21693847/why-is-uniquely-constrained-field-failing-on-update-in-grails) and they say that alter primary key is seems to be not mapped as `id`. If I change mapping by:

```
id column:'user_id', generator: 'assigned'
```

it successfully saves but in table, 2 column named `user_id` appear, 1 presents for `user_id` and other for `id`.

Any solutions will be appreciated.

Thanks.

**Update**

Here is the full code for domain class:

```
class CardUserMaster {
    String card_no
    String user_id
    String password
  static constraints = {
    card_no(nullable: false, blank: false, maxSize: 19, unique: 'user_id')
    user_id(nullable: false, blank: false, maxSize: 10, minSize: 6)
    password(nullable: false, blank: false, maxSize: 32, minSize: 8)
  static mapping = {
        table('CARDUSER_MASTER')
        id name: 'user_id'
        version false
        id generator: 'assigned'
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, it's impossible to have two columns with the same name in the same table. Something else is going on. It would go a long way if you post the code for the domain class.

Comment: Here you are. Emmanuel Rosa.

Answer (score 1):

Update you mappings as :

```
static mapping = {
        table('CARDUSER_MASTER')
        id column:"user_id", name: 'user_id', generator: 'assigned'
        version false
    }
```

We need to provide the actual column name from db for which the primary key is referring to as well as the custom name for the primary key which we want together.

Comment: Was having the same issue under the same circumstances, and adding column solved for me.